# Mouseout handler gets triggered even if my mouse is not out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jquery mouseout handler gets triggered even if my mouse is not out.
Basically my div looks like:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li>
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Category 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Category 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Category 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Category 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and my javascript looks like:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").mouseout(function() {
    console.log("Mouse is out.");
});
```

When I move my cursor from each category to another, the mouseout handler gets called every time. However, my mouse is still on dropdown-menu, right?

Could someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eh....I just find out the answer, what I really should use is mouseleave instead of mouseout.

That fixed it.

Thanks